# How to disable the deadzone for scrolling on MacOS?

Tags: macos

I'm on Sierra, using a regular mouse with a scroll wheel that "ticks" when scrolling. I want to be able to scroll a single "tick" and have that actually do something, right now I have to scroll a few "ticks" at once before it picks up that I scrolled at all. This is really annoying because scrolling becomes something that's way out of control, I either don't scroll as much as I intended or too much. How do I set it to pick up that I scroll even when it's only a single "tick"?

Comment: @Tetsujin It's everywhere, in finder, in the browser, in code files in xcode. I'd rather not use a third party app for this, is there really no setting in the OS to just make it do stuff when I tell it to do stuff?

Comment: What you are describing is not actually default behaviour, I'd test on with different mouse, just in case it's something specific to that one. I use an old Logitech MX518 usually with SteerMouse for 'advanced' functionality; but even using the stock Apple drivers & Control Panel, one tick is one tick in all but that one app [known to display that behaviour on all Macs since an update a couple of years ago]

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not the mouse, it's not the mac. This happens with all mouses and all macs we have here in the office. I have to scroll at least 3 or 4 ticks to make something happen on screen and if I scroll too slowly even 3 or 4 isn't enough. Magic mouses do scroll immediately, even when barely touching the scroll part of it, but those things hurt my wrist.

Comment: I'm really not sure what may be causing it - but I did a quick test. I grabbed a standard Microsoft mouse from one of the PCs & tested on two Macs here [one of which has never seen a mouse before, the other with my 'fancy' driver replacement] Both recognised one 'tick' with no adjustment at all, just 'plug n play'.

Comment: this is a confirmed Sierra bug. We have to wait

Comment: @giammin Can you post a link to the issue, just curious

Comment: @DmitryShvedov confirmed by community..  there are tons of reports online.  There is not an ufficial Apple report (and probably never will be)